# Can a foreign key be the only primary key

Tags: sql

I just have a quick question. Can a table have it's only primary key as a foreign key?

To clarify. When I've been creating tables I sometimes have a table with multiple keys where some of them are foreign keys. For example:

```
create table Pet(
Name varchar(20),
Owner char(1),
Color varchar(10),
primary key(Name, Owner),
foreign key(Owner) referecnes Person(Ssn)
);
```

So now I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like this:

```
create table WorksAs(
Worker char(1),
Work varcahr(30),
primary key(Worker),
foreign key(Worker) references Person(Ssn)
);
```

This would result in two tables having the exact same primary key. Is this something that should be avoided or is it an ok way to design a database? If the above is not a good standard I would simply make the Work variable a primary key as well and that would be fine, but it seems simpler to just skip if it is not needed.

Comment: I think your table WorkAs should be a relational table. This means you can have a table with WorkPlaces for instance, a table with Workers and a table WorksAs to make a relation with Worker->WorkPlace. Otherwise, why don't you use the same table (Worker) and add the column with the char Workplace ?
But answering your question, yes you can have it.

Comment: I'd say it perfectly fine. However... Why not move those fields (in WorksAs) directly into the Person table (being nullable there)? One less table. One less join.

Comment: First of all this is just a bad example I came up with when asking this question seeing as it was easier to explain what I wanted to know. Secondly, the reason I wanted to know this was beacuse I was working with an assignment where we were supposed to elliminate NULL values from our databases. So if I put the WorksAs in the Person table I would have the problem of possible NULL values which I do not want :)

Comment: I follow you as there are lots of data where NULLs are improperly used and that's a bad situation and I guess that's what you are moving away from now. Anyway, I personally would move them over (nullable) to the other table, which with proper naming would be a proper usage of nullable fields, rather that splitting tables. I don't know your full story though and there can be a lot other reasons in splitting tablesso don't want to put a definitive statement here. It seems anyway you have had your questions answered! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Because of the following reasons.

1. Making them the primary key will force uniqueness (as opposed to imply it).
2. The primary key will presumably be clustered (depending on the dbms) which will improve performance for some queries.
3. It saves the space of adding a unique constraint which in some DBMS also creates a unique index

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's perfectly legal to do that.

In fact, this is the basis of [IS-A relations](http://www.geomagas.gr/index.php/is-a-relations-in-relational-databases/) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you might do so. But you need to be careful as foreign keys can have NULL values whereas Primary can't.

Comment: While that's certainly true, the OP specifically asked about "Can a table have it's only primary key as a foreign key?", so I guess (s)he would add a primary key constraint to the detail table, as well.

Comment: Fair enough..But myself being begineer at mysql, the first thing that popped into my mind was that Jesper might facing the problems of NULL values which turn out to be right.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use this approach when mapping inheritance hierarchies using the [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html) or [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) approach,  see e.g. [SQL Alchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html)